# Adding an overlay to og:image

Tags: node.js, express, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I need to generate watermarked embed-image for Facebook in NodeJs. I noticed some websites' facebook posts have a [banner on their image](https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/10/UT-copy-social.png). 
Using NodeJs, I'm wondering what would be the most elegant way to proceed.(ie. Something better than a photoshop action or a PHP script running elsewhere). I guess cropping the image to the right format and adding an overlay PNG with ImageMagik would be viable opion. Are you aware of online services providing this simple functionality?

Since this resource is rarely refreshed from FB, I would not store it on disk and generate it on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can create a banner image using -annotate and composite over your image. For example starting with your image, suppose I want to put a similar banner at the top. I create a semi-transparent background color image of a desired width to match your image and desired height and pointsize. Then I composite it at the top of your image.

```
convert UT-copy-social.png.jpeg \
\( -size 1200x90 xc:"rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" -font Arial -pointsize 64 \
-fill white -gravity east -annotate +50+0 "TEST" \) \
-gravity north -compose over -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If you want a semi-transparent gradient banner, then modify it as follows:

```
convert UT-copy-social.png.jpeg \
\( -size 90x1200 gradient:"rgba(255,0,0,0.5)-rgba(255,0,255,0.5)" \
-rotate 90 -font Arial -pointsize 64 -fill white \
-gravity east -annotate +50+0 "TEST" \) \
-gravity north -compose over -composite result2.jpg
```

[image]

You can also do it similarly with -draw or label:. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/